# Somehow WEBrick is taking over my Sinatra app launch, how to turn it off?

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra, webrick

A while ago, I was fooling around with Node.js (I don't really remember what I did).

Now, whenever I launch Sinatra apps, I get this:

```
mba:sinatra chromium$ ruby basics.rb
[2011-12-16 18:38:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-12-16 18:38:23] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-darwin11.0.1]
== Sinatra/1.3.1 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2011-12-16 18:38:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5708 port=4567
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2011 18:38:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13 0.0072
localhost - - [16/Dec/2011:18:38:51 EST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
- -> /
```

And for each HTTP request, WEBrick logs like 5 more lines.

How do I turn this off? I have no idea why this is happening, because I was doing this with Node.js, not WEBrick.

Comment: Why would anything from `node.js` (a JavaScript-based server implementation) have anything to do with `Sinatra` (a Ruby-based server implementation)? :)

Comment: I have no idea, that's why I'm posting the question :P The last time I saw WEBrick was node.js.

Comment: I'd love to see some `node` output indicating WEBrick anywhere near by :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `ruby basics.rb` means that you are running Sinatra with Ruby, not Node.js.

If you want your Sinatra application launch a simple CGI daemon, not a complete HTTP server, you should use `Sinatra::Base`, not the normal `Sinatra` infrastructure. Applications based on `Sinatra::Base` do not launch WEBRick or any other server at startup and rely on an external HTTP server.

Have a look at [the introduction to `Sinatra::Base`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sinatra%3a%3aBase%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps).

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Nowwww I get it.

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal logging output Sinatra creates.

Check the Readme if you want to turn logging off: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra

Comment: Really? All the tutorials I've seen haven't included it, maybe they've just simplified the terminal output.